# Entity Framework and serialized/remote data access

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm new to entity framework, so forgive me if I'm off-base with my question.   In our environment, our external web servers are located in the DMZ and direct access from the web servers in the DMZ to our SQL server inside the internal firewall is prohibited.   In the past we had created a custom data portal so that sql commands executed from code on the web server would be serialized and remoted to a middleware service inside the firewall, which would then connect to the SQL server execute the command and return a dataset to the caller on web server.

We'd like to look into using Entity Framework.  Are there options within Entity Framework to work within our policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's required to have a direct connection to database via special Entity Framework ADO.NET providers to use entity framework. So looks like it's impossible in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your middleware service inside firewall with RIA Service. RIA Service on the top of Entity Framework will make your middleware service and you will be able to access it and control it easily from outside world.